# configure.ac with CRLF line endings

Tags: newline, configure, autotools, autoconf, automake

If an *Autotools* project is checked out on Windows using *MSys Git* (as opposed to *Cygwin Git*), line endings of the checked-out files will have Windows-native CRLF style (unless configured otherwise in the global `~/.gitconfig`). There're, of course, multiple other ways to obtain the `configure.ac` project file with CRLF line endings.

`autoreconf` can consume such a file and silently produce the executable `configure` script, which, when executed, will produce an obscure error message and exit with code **1**:

```
.in'ig.status: error: cannot find input file: `
```

A capable difftool will show there're regular LF endings mixed with CRLF's in the generated `configure` script:

[image]

Is it possible to somehow tell `autoreconf` (either via command-line switches or via `AC_*` m4 macros) to automatically convert CRLF to LF when reading its input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to somehow tell `autoreconf` (either via command-line switches or via `AC_*` m4 macros) to automatically convert CRLF to LF when reading its input?

`autoreconf`'s `--help` text or [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/autoreconf) would have shown you that no, it does not offer any such command-line option.

There also is no standard Autoconf macro that would serve the purpose (check [its manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.70/autoconf.html#Autoconf-Macro-Index) if you want to confirm), nor do I know or see a way that GNU `m4` can be directly instructed to perform the requested conversion.  (But perhaps there's an `m4` wizard around somewhere who could provide a suitable spell.)